# is_user_logged_in() not working in Firefox

Tags: login

In Firefox (IE, Chrome, and Safari are fine), we are having a problem with is_user_logged_in().

What happens is: a member logs in and is then automatically redirected back to the portal page. This page does not recognize they are logged in (we use is_user_logged_in()) until they refresh the page. Then all is fine after that.

Any ideas?

Here is a small piece of the code which changes the log in/out button based on is_user_logged_in().  Upon log in and redirect, is_user_logged_in() is false until the page is refreshed in browser (Firefox only):

```
<div class="one-half last">

<?php if( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>

<a class="button full-width" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" target="_self">
    Quitter
</a>

<?php else: ?>

<a class="button full-width" href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_self">
    Ouvrir mon portail
</a>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Sorry I'm unable to share the site as it's a private members portal.

Comment: do the domains of the login page / redirect page / refreshed page all match *exactly*? have you tried inspecting cookies to see if the authentication cookie exists on the page where `is_user_logged_in` doesn't work?

Comment: Also, do you have caching installed on the site?

Comment: All domains match exactly.  There is no cookie in Firefox only until you refresh the page.  All other browsers are fine and work properly, even IE (imagine that).

Comment: @StevenJones No there is no caching on the site currently.